# Why did my admin account disappear

Tags: permissions, users

ubuntu 16.04 LTS  When I started my computer my admin acct was gone, now there is only a guest login. Cannot change user either.  When I check user accts it only shows the guest acct.  I tried this:

```
guest-4xiaqd@user-HP-Pavilion-dv7-Notebook-PC:~$ adduser louise
adduser: Only root may add a user or group to the system.
guest-4xiaqd@user-HP-Pavilion-dv7-Notebook-PC:~$ adduser
adduser: Only root may add a user or group to the system.
guest-4xiaqd@user-HP-Pavilion-dv7-Notebook-PC:~$ 
guest-4xiaqd@user-HP-Pavilion-dv7-Notebook-PC:~$ sudo adduser louise
sudo: unable to change to root gid: Operation not permitted
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I didnt change any settings, only logged out and turned it off.

Any answers will need to be very specific because I do not understand what I am doing.

Thanks, everyone.

Comment: Try `CTRL+ALT+F1` or one of the other Fx hotkeys for a textmode terminal and try to login with your admin account there.